# accessing a href element inside li ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have my DOM elements as below

[image]

i want to access 3rd "a href" element inside "ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-caret'" and change it's class "colorpick-btn" to "colorpick-btn selected" and set the class of first "a href" element to "colorpick-btn".

I was only able to come up with below but i can not get it working

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#dropdown-menu dropdown-caret li a").removeClass('colorpick-btn').addClass('colorpick-btn selected');

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: there is no element with id `dropdown-menu`

Comment: how would you know you want to change the 3rd `li a` element

Comment: why are you removing class 'colorpick-btn' and adding the same class again at same time?

Answer (score 1):

Use `li:nth-child(3) a` for the first one, and `:first-child` for the second.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/3GNLr/) - it appears to do what you are asking.

```
$(".dropdown-menu.dropdown-caret li:nth-child(3) a").addClass('selected');
$(".dropdown-menu.dropdown-caret li:first-child a").removeClass('selected');
```

Aside from that, use `.dropdown-menu.dropdown-caret` as opposed to `#dropdown-menu dropdown-caret`..

Comment: You/The poster forgot a period in the selector.

Comment: @TreeTree Thanks - its difficult to tell with the screenshot. I just copy/pasted then modified the code the OP was using... should work now.

Comment: thanks for the answer! due to some reason it's still not working. i'm using a third party theme on my application.so i just wanted to change some color schemes with out changing default styles. https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR.

Comment: @chamara You are using `$(document).ready`, right? Make sure you have jQuery too.. it works in the demo..

Answer (score 1):

```
var $ul = $('.dropdown-colorpicker .dropdown-caret');
$ul.find('.colorpick-btn.selected').removeClass('selected');
$ul.find('.colorpick-btn').eq(2).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, you don't have any elements with id dropdown-menu. Also, dropdown-menu and dropdown-caret are referencing the same element and should not be separated by a space. This should get you started:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".dropdown-menu.dropdown-caret li:eq(2) a").removeClass('colorpick-btn').addClass('colorpick-btn selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use **nth-child** for this.
no need to remove existing class, after selecting element you want, you can add new class like bellow

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dropdown-menu dropdown-caret li:nth-child(3) a").addClass('selected');

    });
</script>
```